# Exception trying to execute Android App from Eclipse To Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have tried to migrate an Eclipse Android project to Android Studio, I have tried both ways, open directly from Android Studio and migrating to Gradle in Eclipse first and then open it in Android Studio.

Then I have tried to remove the Google Play library folder and added it in my Gradle file, and then the project do this:

- Make Project **OK**
- Clean Project **OK**
- Rebuild Project  **OK**
- Gradle sync and download a lot of DLL **OK**
- **Play or Debug KO and gives me this errors:**

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

OR

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

OR

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have started with JDK 1.6, then updated to 1.7 and then to 1.8 to see if that was the problem.

If I don't delete the Google Play Dervices folders the project works just fine.

I'm using a MAC if that is important.

And if that matter to solve this problem, I'm having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025491/android-gradle-sync-exception-with-the-smooth-progress-bar-project) other problem in my project posted in stack overflow.

This is how it looks my project structure:

[image]

And this are the build.grade files of all the projects

Main warper project (guestperience 1.0.1 Moncloa De San Lazaro):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro (this is where I code):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':librarySmartHotel')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

librarySmartHotel:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':main')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

main:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that some configuration is missing (maybe), the true is that I'm super lost.

I'm an iOS programmer and this are my first steps in Android, the project has been done by another guy, and now I'm supposed to continue, so let's say I'm having a good fight with Android Studio and it looks that I'm loosing ;-P

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**

I have found this in the log:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL
>   EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL
>   EXCEPTION:"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex
>   files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"} AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}

Comment: Try unchecking the box Settings->Compiler->Use In-process build then clear cache and restart IDE

Comment: @Eenvincible thanks but that didn't solve the bug

Comment: might be duplicated dependencies:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32973987/3166417

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem come from Android Play Services 7.3.0.

Try :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

or enable multiDex:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName versionNameVar
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

(multiDex solution compile, but might crash at app launch)

Comment: Sorry my friend you where right, the problem was that I have to delete the old libraries from the libs folder.

Comment: It worked for me too. What does multiDex do? why might crash at app launch?

Comment: I don't know why it crashes in some projects, the log were not very clear when I wrote this answer, but if you try and it doesn't crash, you're good to go, otherwise you have to change the version of play services, maybe 8.1.0 solved this issue

Answer (score 4):

After hours with the same problem i found the answer.

The REAL problem is that you have multiple libs with the same classes inside, so the solution would be to either remove the repeating files from one of the libs.

You have to either remove the libs with repeating files or:

1. Open the lib `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` with WinRAR, 7Zip or whatever.
2. Go to `com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal` and delete the files `Command$1.class` and `Command.class`.

In your case you may have to remove other repeating files, not sure because you have many files. Either way, you can also force it to ignore some of those files **IF** the method above didn't work. Put the following code inside the Android block on your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just had to delete the old library.

Answer (score 1):

Try always compile with latest version of google play

try this : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

from : [Setting up google play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)