# Android Gradle sync exception with the Smooth Progress Bar project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add this [library](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar%7Clibrary%7C1.1.0%7C) but when I try to sync Gradle the compiler give me this error:

> Error:(6, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0

And if that matter to solve this problem, I'm having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025223/exception-trying-to-execute-android-app-from-eclipse-to-android-studio) other problem in my project posted in stack overflow.

This is how it looks my project structure:

[image]

And this are the build.grade files of all the projects

Main warper project (guestperience 1.0.1 Moncloa De San Lazaro):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro (this is where I code):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':librarySmartHotel')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

librarySmartHotel:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':main')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

main:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that some configuration is missing (maybe), the true is that I'm super lost.

The only think I can see is that the library is not even downloading in the External Libraries section.

**UPDATE:**

I can see that is something global in my Android Studio, I'm not able to add anything from another data repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add this at the beginning of the file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Also you may have "Offline mode" enabled.**

Check if File -> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Maven/Gradle "Offline work" is enabled, if so just disable it and Sync Gradle.

This was all.

And in my case I have also added this because of the Play Services:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

You will end with a file like this:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':librarySmartHotel')
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when updated android studio to last version then I simply updated Project:Grandle version  to stable  the error's gone