# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on my project and I decided to update my Android Studio into newer version. But after I've imported my project, it shows an error like this:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComEdmodoCropper101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:     Lcom/edmodo/cropper/CropImageView;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at         com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:     Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1) that            doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.android.dx.util.FixedSizeList.<init>(FixedSizeList.java:38)
at com.android.dx.rop.type.StdTypeList.<init>(StdTypeList.java:332)
at com.android.dx.rop.type.StdTypeList.withFirst(StdTypeList.java:398)
at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:371)
at     com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstBaseMethodRef.getPrototype(CstBaseMethodRef.java:81)
at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstBaseMethodRef.getParameterWordCount(CstBaseMethodRef.java:125)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:286)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 1.827 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'Key Alias'
        keyPassword 'keyPassword'
        storeFile file('/Users/username/Desktop/git/project-name/project-name.jks')
        storePassword 'password'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.packageName'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
productFlavors {
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/circularimageview.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.0-rc4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')
compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile files('libs/segmentedcontrol.jar')
compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/mpchartlib.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.3.jar')

}
```

Please help me solve this issue with the new version of Android Studio.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show Complete logcat Error

Comment: Post `build.gradle`.

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'` needs to be updated to `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'`. `preDexLibraries` is false by default.

Comment: @JaredBurrows still giving same error.

Comment: delete old build apk in build folder and try again.

Comment: @yhel That was just my first observation. Do not compile the sources and java docs with the jar. You are bringing the same jar in twice.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I did what you've said. Removed all the redundant compiled dependencies, but still the same.

Comment: This is all you. You are most likely adding the jar in twice. Remove this as well: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`. And update the build.gradle with my past suggestions.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'm getting this Error:Execution failed for task     ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Post stacktrace. There are several questions on stackoverflow that try to help fix that issue. You can try looking for those questions. I would still work on your build.gradle and convert the jars to gradle dependencies. Do not use the libs folder. Do not use `play-services` use the modules you need.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes `app:dexDebug` error is shown when a library is being included more than once in your project. When the error is not related with any dependencies in your app, then it is probably the 65k method limit problem. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output, as shown in the following Gradle build file snippet:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi @heloisasim! Thanks for your suggestion. But I already figured out the solution. God Bless!

Comment: I also got the same issue. can you please post the solution.

Comment: Thanks, a really difficult problem to find. :)

Comment: Thank you!! I've been trying various solutions for the last two hours and this was the one that worked

Answer (score 0):

`multiDexEnabled true` **not solve the problem**, it's only **ignore** it and make bigger APK size then you need, try to find which library is duplicated in dependencies

in my case, gradle already include all my JAR files by this line:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

and there is no need to include any JAR manually